# Is it possible to approximate through medical imaging how old a tendinopathy is?

Tags: tendinopathy, medical-imaging

Is it possible to approximate through medical imaging how old a tendinopathy is?

---

My unsuccessful search so far:

- "tendinopathy age imaging" on https://scholar.google.com and https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/